# Unity rotation is Choppy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple turret on unity that rotates with the mouse.
The turret is made of 4 parts:

- The base (never moves)
- The rotating part (child of the base, rotates only on the Y axes)
- The canon (child of the rotating part, rotates only on the Z axes)
- The camera holder (child of the rotating part, rotates on Y and Z axes, the camera itself is a child of it)

The rotating part has the following script attached to it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovements : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float rotY;
    public float rotZ;
    GameObject Canon;
    GameObject CameraHolder;
    public float maxAngle = 35.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Canon = GameObject.Find("Canon");
        CameraHolder = GameObject.Find("CameraHolder");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rotY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;
        rotZ += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;

        if (rotZ >= 35)
        {
            rotZ = 35;
        }
        else if (rotZ <= 0)
        {
            rotZ = 0;
        }

        Canon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotY, -rotZ);
        CameraHolder.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotY, -rotZ);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotY, 0);
    }
}
```

Now everything works fine but the rotation (especially on the Y axes) is very choppy.
Any idea why?

Comment: As a rule, you **don't** use FixedUpdate.  It doesn't work as you're thinking.  In game engines you use Update and simply apply that deltaTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code looks good, I guess the problem is with the hierarchy, writing positions and not using localPositions.
Example of my hierarchy:

-Base

--Rotating Part

---Canon

----Camera

Changed `FixedUpdate()` to `Update()` and made some changes inside

```
    rotY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;
    rotZ += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;

    if (rotZ >= 35)
    {
        rotZ = 35;
    }
    else if (rotZ <= 0)
    {
        rotZ = 0;
    }
    
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotY, 0);
    Canon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -rotZ); //update only canon localRotation.z because it gets rotation Y from parent (base)
    // don't update camera rotation at all, because it gets rotation from parents (Y from Base and Z from Canon)
```

now it seems pretty smooth.
If you don't need Camera under your GameObject, than move it to the root of hierarchy, so it won't be affected by any parents rotations and update it as you did.

```
CameraHolder.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotY, -rotZ);
```

Comment: As luvjungle says, never use FixedUpdate.  It's not what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I did not look at your code, but if rotation is choppy, you can use Vector3.Lerp or Vector3.Slerp for a beautifully smooth rotation. Something like this:

```
Vector3 rotationTarget;
GameObject objectToRotate;

void Update() {
rotationTarget = Vector3.Lerp(rotationTarget, choppyRotationValue, smoothingFactor);
//Set object rotation to rotationTarget

}
```

Comment: it would be great if you can provide some code snippets